# octave -> gnuplot error: shared library missing

Tags: ubuntu, gnuplot, octave, libreadline

Recently, I upgraded y octave to 3.6.2, but now I cannot plot a contour with `[c, h] = contourf(x,y,z,[0:0.25:3])`. The following error shows that `gnuplot` cannot load a shared library called `libreadline.so.4`

This file doesn't exists in my `/var/lib/` directory. Any idea how to fix this problem:

```
error: get: unknown axes property 
error: called from:
error:   /usr/share/octave/3.6.2/m/plot/colorbar.m at line 139, column 9
error:   /green/s61/mirjalil/MemPMF/acem-acem/forward/loadDataPMF.m at line 24, column 1
gnuplot: error while loading shared libraries: libreadline.so.4: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
gnuplot: error while loading shared libraries: libreadline.so.4: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
warning: broken pipe -- some output may be lost
```

Comment: How did you install/upgrade Octave? Are you on a Windows machine and installing from a binary, or did you use something like fink or macports on a Mac?

Comment: I am using ubuntu 12.04, and had previously upgraded octave with 'sudo apt-get ...'